# How is address reuse prevented in the current wallet implementation?

Tags: security, address-reuse

When trying to send to a foreign address, I got the following error recently:

[image: ERROR: Sending to a used address!]

How does my wallet know, that this address has already been used for sending? It's quite an old address, so I assume I don't have the transaction in my local Tangle any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iri 1.4.2 an API call `wereAddressesSpentFrom` was introduced. This (and later) iri versions come with a [list of previously spent addresses](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/resources/previousEpochsSpentAddresses.txt) bundled. When the API function is called, both the current tangle (after last snapshot) and this list are checked to find transactions that spent from that address.

As a conclusion, your address is most likely on that list.

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed on the list. This list contains roughly 390k addresses, from when on are they being tracked in it? From the genesis transaction or from some later snapshot?

Comment: You'd probably have to ask the foundation. Since the list was committed by alon-e, it is probably compiled from his own list of snapshot databases (http://store.alon-e.com/IOTA_DBs/), which (as he claims - I have not been involved long enough to know when exactly genesis transaction happened) reach back to the genesis transaction.

Comment: Thanks, I created a follow-up question: https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1618/how-does-address-reuse-prevention-affect-scalability
And maybe I'll find out directly here: https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/issues/503
If you have any more information on that, feel free to answer over there!